# Moving Windows from left to right screen in Unity

Tags: unity, window-manager, twinview

I find myself moving windows around a bit in my two-monitor setup (oneiric, unity, twinview). Is there an easy way to move a windows from the left to the right monitor. I know I can move applications from one workspace to another using <kbd>Shift+Alt+Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Cursor-keys</kbd>.

It would be handy to quickly (using hot-keys?) move especially the maximized windows around without using the mouse since they appear to stick rather strongly to their original monitor and ripping them off with a mouse sometimes requires a few attempts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### CCSM answer for 11.04

On Ubuntu 11.04, the compizconfig-settings-manager (CCSM) "Put" plugin can be used to set a shortcut for moving the active window to the next output or monitor in a multiple monitor system.  In the Bindings tab of the Put module under Window Management, set Ctrl+Alt+z (or other if this does not work) as the shortcut for "Put to Next Output"

If Compiz sees your setup as a single monitor, use "Put Within Viewport" Left/Right instead (forum thread [1588821](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588821))

### Warning about CCSM on 11.10

CCSM is **broken** on Ubuntu 11.10, in part because it uses gconf2 backend, in part because it disables Unity plugin due to keybinding conflicts with its own plugins.  As a result, the unity launcher disappears.

To get the launcher back, remove the *~/.config/compiz-1* directory.   You can obtain a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F2, or a Nautilus window with Ctrl+N from the desktop (from where you can run /usr/bin/xterm), or Ctrl+Alt+T to launch Terminal.  For ccsm config purge, remove *.gconf/apps/compiz-1/* and *.gconf/apps/compizconfig-1/* and *~/.compiz-1*, and then run *unity --reset* for unity defaults.

*Way forward*: Using *dconf* and *dconf-tools* it may be possible to configure a shortcut by directly modifying the config tree.

---

Postscript by @DrSAR: The CCSM steps did not work for the OP (even though [others have benefited from it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fquxoYPxyEI)). This might be related to the [problem of compiz seeing only one monitor](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1588821).

PS: Use at your own risk since somehow installing and using compizconfig-settings-manager eventually disabled unity for the OP to the point of a seemingly irretrievable launcher and panel.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions - I have performed steps 1. - 3. but somehow the shortcut has no effect. Windows stubbornly stay put. Is there a record / log I can inspect to see that I am actually getting the instructions through to compiz?

Comment: bummer - after clicking around a bit the system slowed to a crawl and now my dash and launcher have disappeared and I can't get them back. Purging compizconfig-settings-manager and 'unity --reset' and deleting gconf2 setting all don't help. I think I'm going xfce now...

Comment: Graham, I will accept this as an answer since I have read that some people have successfully been able to get this to work. But I think I'll put a warning in your answer if you don't mind. Feel free to remove since this has changed your answer in its meaning from what you said.

Comment: @DrSAR I had uninstalled ccsm due to my problems in [78237](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78237/unity-3d-with-nvidia-driver-becomes-very-slow-and-laggy).   I've tried it again and indeed the launcher disappeared.  Updated answer.  To get the launcher back, remove ~/.config/compiz-1

Comment: I just wanted to add that the fix for 11.04 works for 12.04 also.

Answer (score 2):

Some days ago the best solution was *[Extra WM Actions](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Extrawm)* Compiz plugin with its *Move window to next output*. It worked exceptionally well, much better than *Put* plugin, which often is unusable (btw. for window alignment one can find useful a *Grid* plugin).

However the option disappeared some time ago. I'm still on 10.04 LTS at my laptop mostly because of this feature lack under 11.10 and its couple predecessors.

I know this is a poor answer, but maybe there is a chance to bring back this feature as it had existed before?